# Displaying of 5 inputted number using While loop in R Program

Tags: r, loops, while-loop

can someone help me how can I fix this? Because I need to input 5 values in my program and the output must display the even numbers on that list.

```
item<-as.integer(readline(prompt = "Enter a number :"))
while(item <= 6){
  print(item)
  item <- item +1
  if(item%%2==0){
    break
  }
}
```

and the output is just like this.

```
Enter a number :5
[1] 5
>
```

Comment: That's because you break out of the loop during the first iteration. 5 + 1 = 6 and 6 is even.

Comment: Do you want to input 5 values, or do you want to input one value of "5"?  How do you plan to collect more values beyond the first one?  Or do you expect something like a comma-delimited string?

Comment: I want to input 5 values and the output must display the even numbers.

Comment: Do you want to collect them one by one, or all at once (e.g., the user types "1, 2, 3, 4, 5")?

Comment: I want them to be collected one by one

Comment: So then presumably you want the line that collects the input to be inside a loop, right?  Is there a reason your current code collects only one input?